Android tombstone notification/callback?
Just wondering if there is any way to register a callback or get a notification when a tombstone is generated? I have a way to read the logs from my app, but instead of blindly polling, if there is a way to read only when it's been created, that'll be great

Found a way to detect this via the DropBox add entry system broadcast intent
